# Get image dimension in angular 2

Tags: html, angular

I am writing code to upload an image file. I need to know the dimensions(height and width) of the image that will be uploaded before I call the function to upload.

Is there a way in angular 2 by which I can extract the image dimension? If so, how?

Comment: You have to obtain the image object itself, and then ask for the sizes. How does your code look like?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I created function to get image size

```js
getImgSize(imageSrc: string): Observable<ISize> {
    let mapLoadedImage = (event): ISize => {
        return {
            width: event.target.width,
            height: event.target.height
        };
    }
    var image = new Image();
    let $loadedImg = fromEvent(image, "load").pipe(take(1), map(mapLoadedImage));
    // Rxjs 4 - let $loadedImg = Observable.fromEvent(image, "load").take(1).map(mapLoadedImage);
    image.src = imageSrc;
    return $loadedImg;
}
```

`interface ISize { width: number; height: number; }`
Also you can subscribe on load event in html
`<img (load)="loadedImg($event)" [src]="imageSrc">` and get size from it.

Comment: This worked great for me. In my case I needed it to be blocking, so I used await/async

Comment: What would this look like for RxJS6?

Comment: `let $loadedImg = fromEvent(image, "load").pipe(take(1), map(mapLoadedImage))`

Answer (score 7):

With the Angular2 approach, I'll create a custom directive to get the height and width of **any element**. For `img`, I'll apply it(directive) in the `img` tag and whenever I want to get the height & width of an img, I just need click it. You can modify according to your need.

**DEMO : https://plnkr.co/edit/3tibSEJCF734KQ3PBNZc?p=preview**

**directive.ts**

```
import { Directive,Input,Output,ElementRef,Renderer} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector:"[getHeightWidth]",
  host:{
    '(click)':"show()"
  }
})

export class GetEleDirective{ 

  constructor(private el:ElementRef){

  }
  show(){
    console.log(this.el.nativeElement);

    console.log('height---' + this.el.nativeElement.offsetHeight);
    console.log('width---' + this.el.nativeElement.offsetWidth);   
  }
}
```

**app.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `

  <div style="width:200px;height:300px">
       <img getHeightWidth                 <!-- here I'm using getHeightWidth directive-->
            [src]="source" alt="Angular2" 
            width="100%" 
            height="100%">  
   </div>
  `,

})
export class AppComponent {
  source='images/angular.png';
}
```

Comment: For offsetHeight I get something sensible. For offsetWidth, I get 0. What gives? The image clearly displays.

Answer (score 6):

In case if you need to get the image size in ts file:

```
getImageDimension(image): Observable<any> {
    return new Observable(observer => {
        const img = new Image();
        img.onload = function (event) {
            const loadedImage: any = event.currentTarget;
            image.width = loadedImage.width;
            image.height = loadedImage.height;
            observer.next(image);
            observer.complete();
        }
        img.src = image.url;
    });
}
```

Call above method:

```
const image = {
  url: 'https://kalgudi.com/store/assets/images/e-mahila1.jpg',
  context: 'Mahila self help group'
}
this.getImageDimension(image).subscribe(
   response => { 
     console.log(response);
   }
);
```

Answer (score 5):

Simply you can use following code to get the width and height (Resolution) of the Image.

**HTML Code**

```
<img #pic [src]="imgURL" (load)="onLoad()>
```

**In Angular**

```
@ViewChild('pic', { static: false }) pic: ElementRef;
onLoad() {
   console.log((this.pic.nativeElement as HTMLImageElement).naturalWidth);
   console.log((this.pic.nativeElement as HTMLImageElement).naturalHeight);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

**In component.ts**

```
  this.uploadService.validateandUploadFile(files, 300, 300);
```

**In service.ts file**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk/global';
import * as S3 from 'aws-sdk/clients/s3';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';




  FOLDER = '/';
    
    imageUrl = "";
    
    resData: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject(null);
    
    data = { message: "", data: "" };
    
    constructor() { }
    validateandUploadFile(file, Iheight, Iwidth) {
    
        let fileToUpload = file;
        if (fileToUpload.type == "image/jpeg" || fileToUpload.type == "image/png" || fileToUpload.type == "image/jpeg") {
            //Show image preview
            let reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = (event: any) => {
                var img = new Image();
                img.onload = () => {
                    let width = img.width;
    
                    let height = img.height;
                    if (width <= Iwidth && height <= Iheight) {
                        this.imageUrl = event.target.result;
    
                        this.uploadfile(file);
                    } else {
    
                        this.data.message = "You can maximum upload " + Iheight + " * " + Iwidth + " File";
                        this.data.data = "";
                        this.resData.next(this.data);
                        return this.resData;
                    }
                };
    
                img.src = event.target.result;
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(fileToUpload);
        } else {
            this.data.message = "You can't be able to upload file except JPG and PNG format";
            this.data.data = "";
            this.resData.next(this.data);
            return this.resData;
        }
    }


uploadfile(file) {

    if (file != null) {
        const bucket = new S3(
            {
                accessKeyId: '***********************',
                secretAccessKey: '**********************************',
                region: 'us-east-2'
            }
        );
        const params = {
            Bucket: '*********',
            Key: file.name,
            Body: file,
            ACL: 'public-read'

        };
        var that = this;

        bucket.upload(params, function (err, data) {

            if (err) {
                console.log('There was an error uploading your file: ', err);
                return false;
            }


            console.log('Successfully uploaded file.', data);
            that.data.message = "Successfully uploaded file.";
            that.data.data = data.Location;
            that.resData.next(that.data);
            return that.resData;
        });

    }

}
```

Answer (score -9):

You have to use JS code to find the height and width of image as follow :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
function readURL(input)
{
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#image1')
            .attr('src', e.target.result);              
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

function upload()
{
    var img = document.getElementById('image1');
    var width = img.clientWidth;
    var height = img.clientHeight;  
    alert(width + " : " + height);

    //check height and width using above two variables (width/height) in if block and place upload code in if block...
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" /><input type="button" value="Upload" onClick="upload()" /><br>
<img id="image1" src="#" alt="your image" height="auto" width="auto" />
</body>
</html>
```

In above code we have to place selected image in image element, after during upload process check height and width and process to upload.

Thanks...

Comment: I can't imagine why if question is clearly about angular2, how can jQuery help here?