# Hide image based on dimensions in Angular/Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm accessing a API which contains images and other metadata. The problem I have is that some of the entries have a image placeholder under the linked URL. Based on the dimensions(height/width) I would like to hide those images.

In [Get image dimension in angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41158232/get-image-dimension-in-angular-2) it is necessary to click the image. This is not an option for me.

What options exist to get a working showImage() function?

```
<ion-col width-50 *ngFor="let file_uri of row" image-dimension>
  <div *ngIf="showImage()">
        <img [src]="file_uri">
  </div>
</ion-col>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a matchMedia filter.

```
app.filter("matchMedia", function($window) {
return function matchMedia (mediaQueryString) {
    return $window.matchMedia(mediaQueryString).matches;
}});
```

Then use it in directives:

```
<div ng-if="'(min-width: 400px)' | matchMedia">
<h1>The viewport is at least 400 pixels wide</h1></div>
```

Comment: This looks like angular.js. Is there a solution for Angular 4?

Comment: I am going to try in angular 4. if I will get any solution then I will inform you. ok

Comment: Thank you. That would be awesome.

Comment: Has someone another idea. I haven't found this functionality in Ionic3/Angular4.