# CSS anchor tag not taking child image width when resized with percentage

Tags: javascript, html, css

To make a long story short, I have several draggable images on a map that are wrapped with anchor tags (`<a><img></a>`) so that they can be dragged via keyboard as well. The original size of the images vary from image to image, but they are all too big, so I scaled them down to 20% of their original sizes like so:

```css
img {
   width: 20%;
}
```

The problem I am having is that the anchor tags are retaining the original image size width:

[image: screenshot 1]

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/n8egfdb9/

I am aware that the anchor tag width can be forced by providing a `width` with the same number of pixels as the image, but that is not an option since I have hundreds of images of all different sizes and don't know what the width is.

Unfortunately `width: fit-content` does not work on the anchor tag.

I did try using JS to fetch the image size and then apply with matching width and height, which worked, but then when it came to resizing the screen, it is not responsive. And I am not aware of any JS methods that listen for when an element is resized responsively.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you set a percentage to a class you are saying how large that object should be compared to it's parent. So when you say

```css
.dropped-sticker {
  width: 20%;
}
```

You are saying that the image's width should be 20% of that of the `<a>` tag.

You can instead set the  tag width to be 20% of it's parent, the `<div>`, and set the image to be 100% of the `<a>` tag, so that it won't overflow. That way the image size will be proportionate to the map-panel.

```css
.sticker-cont {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 165px;
  left: 270px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  width: 20%;
}
.dropped-sticker {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: thank you, but I need 20% of the image's original size. If I set the width of the anchor tag to 20%, it does 20% of map element.

Comment: @Aristocles the only option I can think is to get the image size, then set it to be 20% of it's size programatically. To get the size you can try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49115089/11584310